# Log Shipping with Clustered Instance- back up

Tags: sql-server, backup, transaction-log, clustering, log-shipping

Current Set up- Clustered Instance Active/Passive
Node  -1
Node  -2
Current Back ups goes to Network Drive
Cluster Drive

E drive

Virtual Name ABC
Shared Folder - e\Share

New instance- for Log Shipping

My question is if i set up a log shipping between clustered instance will it break my current back ups that goes to the network

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. You can continue to have the backups on the FCI go to your network share. The log shipping job can be configured to copy from the network share to a local drive on the new instance, or read right from the network share.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am planning for a standard set up and the back up folder will reside on the cluster disk where the cluster data and log file resides, but create a separate folder and share so that the secondary server comes and grabs the log files.

Comment: As long as you are only doing one set of log backups per database, and both ends of the log shipping process can access the location, you are fine.

Comment: But i have my default back ups that is part of the maintenance plan which goes over network and there is the log back up of log shipping, will the log back up for the log  shipping break my log back up of the maintenance plan